# Sending bulk data to Azure ML Endpoint

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, endpoint

I have an Azure ML endpoint which is used to get scoring when I supply data in json.

```
import requests
import json

# URL for the web service
scoring_uri = 'http://107a119d-9c23-4792-b5db-065e9d3af1e6.eastus.azurecontainer.io/score'  

# If the service is authenticated, set the key or token
key = '##########################'


data = {"data":
           [{'Associate_Gender': 'Male', 'Associate_Age': 20, 'Education': 'Under Graduate', 'Source_Hiring': 'Internal Movement', 'Count_of_Incoming_Calls_6_month': None, 'Count_of_Incoming_Calls_6_month_bucket': 'Greater than equal to 0 and less than 4', 'Internal_Quality_IQ_Score_Last_6_Months': '93%', 'Internal_Quality_IQ_Score_Last_6_Months_Bucket': 'Greater than 75%', 'Associate_Tenure_Floor_Bucket': 'Greater than 0 and less than 90', 'Current_Call_Repeat_Yes_No': False, 'Historical_CSAT_score': 'Greater than equal to 7 and less than 9', 'Customer_Age': 54, 'Customer_Age_Bucket': 'Greater than equal to 46', 'Network_Region_Originating_Call': 'East London', 'Length_of_Relationship_with_Customer': 266, 'Length_of_Relationship_with_Customer_bucket': 'Greater than 90', 'Call_Reason_Type_L1': 'Voice', 'Call_Reason_Type_L2': 'Prepaid', 'Call_Reason_Type_L3': 'Request for Reversal Provisioning', 'Number_of_VAS_services_active': 6, 'Customer_Category': 'Mercury', 'Customer_monthly_ARPU_GBP_Bucket': 'More than 30', 'Customer_Location': 'Houslow'}]
                        }
# Convert to JSON string
input_data = json.dumps(data)

# Set the content type
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
# If authentication is enabled, set the authorization header
headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {key}'

# Make the request and display the response
resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, input_data, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

How to send input data from files in bulk and get output. Or is it not feasible to send huge amount of data for scoring on endpoints?
Any alternative suggestion for scoring on azure is also welcome.

Comment: You can send bulk requests, but it depends on your app/api.
i.e lets say if you have a flask app, if you send multiple requests to a simple app, then it will process in a queue. So, you have to enable multiprocessing. Check out [gevent](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a folder called `json_data`, where all your json files are stored, then you would open these files and post them to your endpoint as follows:

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import glob

your_uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'
folder_path = './json_data'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.json')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        json_input_data = json.load(f)
        resp = requests.post(your_uri, json_input_data)
        print(resp)
```

To showcase the successful http response 201 with `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` you have to create a folder in the same directory of your python file and name it `json_data`, then create a few json files inside the folder and paste some data into the files, e.g.:

file1.json:

```
{
  "title": "some title name 1",
  "body": "some body content 1"
}
```

file2.json:

```
{
  "title": "some title name 2",
  "body": "some body content 2"
}
```

etc.

You could easily rewrite it and use your own uri, key, headers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To send bulk data for inferencing, I recommend to create a **Batch Endpoint**,
in **Azure ML** and the best way to do it is using the **Azure CLI**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-endpoint#create-a-batch-endpoint

You can then start a batch scoring using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-endpoint#start-a-batch-scoring-job-using-the-azure-cli

Or using REST:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-endpoint#start-a-batch-scoring-job-using-rest